# Generate PDF from Net Core

Tags: library, pdf, programming

I want to generate PDF files from my net core app, I was searching on internet, but there are many options for libraries.

Could you suggest a good library or a package to generate PDF files from net core?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome Matias!  Can you please edit your question to define what specific qualities you are seeking that would make a library good?

Comment: Actually, i found a library called iTextSharp. It has a lot of characteristics and you can use in net core project

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i found a library called iTextSharp. It has a lot of characteristics and you can use in net core project

Comment: Hi again Matías.  Would you be so kind as to add more content to your answer explaining a bit why you like the library you found, and a little info regarding the characteristics it has?  Thanks!